# Unable to select an element from calendar dropdown using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am unable to select a value from a calendar dropdown using selenium webdriver. The calendar dropdown contains few options to select along with dates, I am able to select the dates but not the other values.

```html
<div class="dropDownDateBox OCYEKPD-yc-a" id="gwt-debug-lineItemType-startDateBox">
    <input type="text" class="gwt-DateBox">
    <span> </span>
    <input type="text" class="timepicker">
    <span class="gray">EDT</span>
    <div tabindex="0" class="OCYEKPD-E-c OCYEKPD-E-l" role="button" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
        <input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">          
        <span class="OCYEKPD-E-a"></span>
        <div class="OCYEKPD-E-j goog-inline-block">Immediately</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-lineItemType-startDateBox")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gwt-debug-lineItemType-startDateBox']/div/div")).click();
```

Comment: please check the images. The links are not there. Additionally, add stacktrace and additional message.

Comment: sorry, i am restricted to upload images.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: It's an common issue with data picker. Is that a date picker?

Comment: Your first code line is clicking an element that you didn't provide. Please provide the relevant HTML. What element are you trying to click? Your code samples are clicking two different elements.

Comment: It's a date picker but the value i want to select is not a date, it's an option above date picker.

Comment: first code line clicks the input box to open the calendar and shows the date picker alongwith the value i want to select

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted through the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gwt-debug-lineItemType-startDateBox']/input[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Immediately']")).click();
```

Thanks everyone for your help! Really appreciate.